# data-ng-change cannot pass a parameter to the function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown list, which is a combination of two values: engine.number and engine.name. After an option is selected passNumber() function should be called. The function is called after the selection of the option, but it does not pass the "engine.number" value. It becomes 'undefined' when I debug the js function. What am I missing here?

HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
    <select class="span3" ng-model="selectedEngine" ng-options='engine.element as (engine.number + " " + engine.name) for engine in engines' data-ng-change="passNumber(engine.number)">
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    </select> &nbsp;
    <span class="help-inline" id="loadingEngines" rel="spinner"></span>
</div>
```

Function:

```
$scope.passNumber = function(number) {
    //do something
}
```

Edit:

I tried selectedEngine, selectedEngine.number, engine, engine.number to pass they are all 'undefined'

Comment: data-ng-change="passNumber(engine.number)" change it with data-ng-change="passNumber(selectedEngine.number)"

Comment: @wickY26 Still 'undefined'

Answer (score 2):

It's because it has no idea which repeated instance you're trying to pass. You need to pass in the `ngModel` - so change your model to be the entire object and pass that:

```
<select class="span3" ng-model="selectedEngine" ng-options='engine as (engine.number + " " + engine.name) for engine in engines' data-ng-change="passNumber(selectedEngine.number)">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I still get 'undefined'. This surely looks correct, but there something else that I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

First to all... 
Is the select loading data? Maybe you´re not using an controller directive.

```
<div class="controls" data-ng-controller="MyController">
<select class="span3" ng-model="selectedEngine" ng-options='engine.element as (engine.number + " " + engine.name) for engine in engines' data-ng-change="passNumber(engine.number)">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
</select> &nbsp;
<span class="help-inline" id="loadingEngines" rel="spinner"></span>
```

Comment: Yes it loads the data, and it's connected to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-options's `data-ng-change` to pass in the `selectedEngine` from ng-model:

```
<div class="controls">

    <select class="span3" ng-model="selectedEngine" ng-options='engine.element as (engine.number + " " + engine.name) for engine in engines' data-ng-change="passNumber(selectedEngine)">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>

</select> &nbsp;
{{ selected }}
</div>
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBVpTkJLKbUir4VQFUe8?p=preview)

Comment: Fixed the code, I accidentally had pasted the wrong html - see plunkr for working example